# volume shader inside of a glass material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, volumetrics, glass

I am trying to create a scene of nebula trapped in a glass cube,I have sucessfully created nebula by using principled volume,however whenever I try to put a transsimisive cube around it,cycles compeletely ignoring my noise texture node and my color ramps node.what did I do wrong here?I have increased light path on volume,it did nothing for me.

[image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: It looks like the glass isn’t smooth. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, and its very frustrating. Volumes inside a refractive shader dont work in cycles. i mix a transparent shader with the glass shader (factor 0.5)  to get the volumetric shader half visible.
I recommend reporting it as a bug (you are not the first one) to show the demand of combining volumetrics and refraction. I hope this will be dealt with soon by cycles developers.